# Telling a Separate Window to Scroll

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I need to be able to programmatically scroll a window up and down given only a point on a screen. I've managed to retrieve a handle using Windows API, but I am unable to get it to scroll up or down.

Assume the following code:

```
//retrieves the correct window.
IntPtr      hWnd = Win32.WindowFromPoint(new Point(xPos, yPos));

Win32.Rect  rect = default(Win32.Rect);

//retrieves a rectangle with the desired windows dimensions 
Win32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rect);

//Insert scroll code here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [SendMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with [WM_VSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [WM_HSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages?

Also check [SetScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (pInvoked version [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setscrollinfo)). Even [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=446352&p=1686041) post may be helpful to you.

Comment: Advise against SetScrollInfo; this is what controls use internally to update the scrollbar position, but it won't affect the control's internal state, and instead you'll end up with a scrollbar out-of-sync with the visuals. WM_H/VSCROLL are your best bet.

Comment: The post you provided actually provided the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

to scroll a window you need to send it a windows message by calling `SendMessage` with the appropriate parameters - for full details regarding scrolling and associated messages etc. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

UPDATE - as per comments:

Another option might be to call [`ScrollWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the `hWnd` - as per comments calling `ScrollwindowEx` should NOT be used since it would create an inconsistency between the displayed state and the internal state of the respective window!

Comment: Definitely do not want to use ScrollWindowEx; that may move the bits around on the screen, but the underlying control will continue to act as though it's still at the old position (since its internal state won't have been changed), causing much confusion to the user!